# Memory leakage:Received memory warning. Level=1 & 2 in cocos2d

Tags: memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie to cocos2d and facing memory problem.
I m getting memory warning level 1 & 2.

1. I have two scenes in my game.
2. In first scene(mainmenu) I have button(on click it will replace scene with 2nd one i.e (StartMoving))
3. In StartMoving.h file I have intialized sprites,arrays(which I am deallocating in      dealloc method)
4. In my init method of StartMoving I have intialized background Image.(realeased in dealloc method) and going to the Allreset method.
5. This is my code of the Allreset method.

-(void)AllReset
{
while(x==5)
    {
        x=0;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[mainmenu scene]];     //Replacing scene when X=5

```
}  

CCLOG(@"%@: %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),self);  
CCSprite *tra=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tra.png"];             
    tra.position =ccp(800,115);                                     
    [self addChild:tra z:0 tag:2];                                  
        [tra1 insertObject:tra atIndex:0];      //tra1 is NSMutablearray which is realeased in dealloc                       

NSLog(@"tra is loaded....");  

//[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"police.wav"];      

NSArray *name14 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"app1.plist",@"app2.plist",@"app3.plist",@"app4.plist",@"app5.plist", nil];                                         

NSArray *name24 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"app1.png",@"app2.png",@"app3.png",    @"app4.png",@"app5.png",nil];                                            

NSArray *name34 =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];  

NSString *file14=[name14 objectAtIndex:x];      
NSString *file24=[name24 objectAtIndex:x];  
NSString *file34=[name34 objectAtIndex:x];  

int frame[]={3, 7, 11, 4, 5};             
float Fdelay[]={0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1,0.5};           

CCSpriteFrameCache *frameCache4 =[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];  
[frameCache4    addSpriteFramesWithFile:file14];  
CCSpriteBatchNode *danceSheet4 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:file24];  
[self addChild:danceSheet4];  

CCSprite *sprite4 = [CCSprite node];  
sprite4.position = ccp(395,155);  
[tra addChild:sprite4 z:1 tag:14];  

NSMutableArray *animFrames4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frame[x]];  
for(int i = 1; i <= frame[x]; i++) {  
    NSString *namef4=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",file34,i];  
    CCSpriteFrame *frame4 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:namef4];  
    [animFrames4 addObject:frame4];  
}  

CCAnimation *anim4 = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames4 delay:Fdelay[x]];  
CCAnimate *animN4 = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim4];  
CCRepeatForever *repeat4 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animN4];    
[sprite4 runAction:repeat4];   
    id move= [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5.5f position:CGPointMake(240,115)];            
id easeout=[CCEaseOut actionWithAction:move rate:1.5f];  
id menudisp=[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(menudisplay:)];  
[train1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:easeout,menudisp, nil]];
```

}

1. I have shown only one animation here but there are total 7 animation on the same sprite tra.
2. When tra stops at a given point, menu label will be displayed. and when user taps label it starts moving in the same direction & goes out of the screen. As soon as the whole sprite goes out of the screen one method is called which cleans up the memory of tra(I think with that only tra's children will be cleaned up. correct me if i am wrong..)
3. After cleaning the memory it will again call Allreset method with increamented x value.

`-(void)Incrementingx
{ 
    x++;
    [self Allreset];
}

### `

I have also used following things in applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method of appdelegate.m

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];           //note this is commented

Application is running perfectly fine on simulator but on device :(
please help me :(

Answer (score 4):

I faced some sort of same problem before while I was using a lot of sprite sheet and sprite sheet animations & using simple animations. Also while calling different scenes or switching between scenes. These are all what I did.

1. Add the following codes in your dealloc not in delegate.m

```
//IF you have particular spritesheets to be removed! Don't use these if you haven't any
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"ufoRotateThird2.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"ufoRotateSecond1.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"explode.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"explodeR.plist"];

//Use these
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];


//Use these
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];

//Try out and use it. Not compulsory
[self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup: YES];
```

1. In the init unschedule all the selectors first.
2. Unschedule all the selectors when the scenes switches

Comment: Make sure your scene's dealloc is calling!

Comment: The scene's dealloc is called only at the end of the scene(when scene switch happens). But my application is crashing before the scene is switched. Do I have to call dealloc when the scene is running.

Comment: no! then you need to call these in intermediate functions as needed... beginning of the function which you call often... which you consider crashing at...

Comment: These methods fixed my problem, but I found I needed to call them at the beginning of each scene's init, not in dealloc. (Dealloc was being called *after* my next scene's init, resulting in two scene's worth of textures being loaded at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this memory warning before. I only got it on an iOS device, not on the Simulator, and I've found it's because there are too many are running the background (iOS 4.x). Just close those apps and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 1):

instead you remove in dealloc.Better put inside onExit. because dealloc sometimes will cause a problem when you want add spriteframes in the next scenes.

```
-(void) onExit{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
    [super onExit];
}
```